# Credits: Error occurs *sometimes*

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-credits, credits

I created a Facebook app and integrated Credits.  However, about every second time I call the credits API, I get the following error:

*There Was a Problem Processing Your Payment / Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again later.*

Everything on my end looks good.  On success, the callback is called 3 times:

1. payments_get_items
2. payments_status_update, status "placed"
3. payments_status_update, status "settled"

When it fails and the above error dialog is shown, I can see that only the first call is performed (payments_get_items).

I can see that the response back to Facebook is the same in both cases:

```
{ "content":[ { "item_id":"1", "title":"[title]", "description":"[description]", "image_url":"[url]", "product_url":"[url]", "price":30 } ], "method":"payments_get_items" }
```

Has anyone experienced this or can imagine what the reason for the behaviour is?

Thank you!

Bw

Comment: You need to be absolutely sure your response to the callback is correct - this is the most likely reason for a failure here - do you see two calls to your server for the 'placed' status?

Comment: @lgy: The response is identical in both cases.  When the error dialog comes up, I get no payments_status_update call.  When the correct dialog comes up, I get one payments_status_update with status "placed" and one with status "settled".

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar issue. 
Error message is generic and it doesn't give you exact cause of the problem.

In my case the problem was that my image url was misspelled so check your payments_get_items response very carefully.

Beside checking image url validity also check that length of your title and description is ok. 
check "Developers response" section on this url for info on boundaries : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/callback/#payments_get_items

BTW, I think they mistakenly marked product url as required, however you can put same value as for image url just to be sure.